# django-celery-beat spams due tasks

Tags: django, celery, django-celery-beat

I'm using `django-celery-beat` for some hourly/daily tasks. However, strange behaviour made me clueless what to do.

I'm creating a task using this piece of code:

```
    periodic_task = apps.get_model('django_celery_beat', 'PeriodicTask')
    interval_schedule = apps.get_model('django_celery_beat', 'IntervalSchedule')

    schedule, _ = interval_schedule.objects.get_or_create(every=2, period='hours')

    periodic_task.objects.update_or_create(
        task=TASK,
        defaults={'name': '<task description>', 'interval': schedule},
    )
```

where `TASK` is a string pointing to this task:

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def task():
    <things to do>
    pass
```

In the code you see that I use an interval of 2 hours, and once I started the beat with `celery -A [project-name] beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`, no error pops up (I don't know if it actually works, 2 hours is a lot of time). However, when I change the interval to 1 hour, it spams these:

```
[2021-12-21 15:32:45,333: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.tasks.task[6c0343b0-faf1-4eae-a8e0-721c862120a9] succeeded in 0.0s: None
[2021-12-21 15:32:45,336: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task <task description> (app.tasks.task)
```

and then it continues to eternity, only stoppable with Ctrl+C.

I do have the RabbitMQ Management plugin installed, and from the UI everyting looks fine - no queue, nothing unacked, etc. Any clue what this could cause?

Even after purging the queue, it still happens (with `celery -A [project-name] purge`).

Answer (score 0):

Update, I found the answer here: https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/issues/95. My `TIME_ZONE` setting was wrong (still set to UTC rather my actual timezone, Europe/Amsterdam), so I guess that's where it messed up.